# Scala with Play Framework 2.3.6: sending a message to all socket clients

Tags: scala, sockets, playframework

I'm new to Scala and the Play Framework, so I'm experimenting a bit.
I've successfully created websockets, but I'd like to be able to send a message to multiple socket clients from a simple POST request.

For instance, I have 10 different random browsers connected to my socket (**ws:// ... /websocket**), and I can myself send a "POST: HELLO" to **/newMessage**. How do I make so this "HELLO" gets sent to each of the 10 clients ?

Here's the controller receiving the HELLO. Works fine and prints "**Got: AnyContentAsText(HELLO)**" :

```
def newMessage = Action { implicit request =>
    println("Got: " + request.body)
    /* add something here to send "request.body" to every socket client */
    Ok("Got: " + request.body)
}
```

And here's my simple "Socket" controller that sends "Welcome" to connected clients :

```
object Socket extends Controller {
def txSocket = WebSocket.using[String] { request =>
    // Log events to the console
    val in = Iteratee.foreach[String](println).map { _ =>
        println("Disconnected")
    }

    // Send a single 'Welcome!' message
    val out = Enumerator("Welcome!")

    (in, out)
 }
}
```

How can I, from my "Message" controller, send **request.body** to the websocket ?

Thank you for your time !

Comment: Are you looking for a solution that uses iteratees or a Akka/Actor one is also good? See: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.6/ScalaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-with-actors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each websocket connection makes a new actor. You need to select the actors and send the message to them.

Like so.

```
    object Application extends Controller {

      def connect = WebSocket.acceptWithActor[JsValue, JsValue] { request => out =>
        ClientActor.props(out)
      }

      def broadcast = Action { _ =>
        system.actorSelection("akka://application/system/websockets/*/handler") ! "msg"
        Ok
      }

      def system = play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka.system(play.api.Play.current)
    }
```

Comment: It seems to be what I was looking for. I'm having trouble sending messages to the clients (they never receive them) but I will figure it out. Thank you once again !